# How to get FindsByAttribute from IWebElement in C# Selenium ? [Page Object Model]

Tags: c#, selenium, wait, pageobjects

Given the Page Object Model design pattern in Selenium, I need to check if the WebElement is present/enabled/clickable on the page before performing an action on it.

The base 'Page' class:

```
 public class Page
{            
    public Page()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(SeleniumTests.driver, this);
    }  
}
```

An inherited class:

```
class Page_Certificate_ChooseOperator : Page
    {               
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "SearchOperatorName")]
        public IWebElement txtName { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "SearchOperatorEstablishmentNumber")]
        public IWebElement txtEstablishmentNumber { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "searchButton")]
        public IWebElement btnSearch { get; set; }

        public void SelectOperator(String name, String establishmentNumber)
        {
            this.txtName.SetInputField(name);
            this.txtEstablishmentNumber.SetInputField(establishmentNumber);                
            this.btnSearch.SafeClick();
        }           
    }
```

Finally the class for the extension methods:

```
 public static class SeleniumExtensionMethod
    {
        public static void SetInputField(this IWebElement webElement, String value)
        {
            webElement.Clear();
            webElement.SendKeys(value);
        }    

        public static void SafeClick(this IWebElement webElement, int timeout_in_seconds)
        {     
            //This is the difficult part. I need to check if the webElement is visible, but I don't want to write "low-level" code and specify the ID and  selector. Is there a way I can find out how the webElement was created by this class and say something like "webElement.How" to find "How.ID" or "webElement.Using" to find "btnSearch"? I need to use something like the below code using the PageObject
            // WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumTests.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            // IWebElement dynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>(driver => driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSearch")));  
            // dynamicElement.Click();

            //Now, I just use this, but it crashes on NoSuchElementFound since it goes too fast. I don't want to use ImplicitWait.
            btnSearch.Click();


        }
    }
```

The challenge I'm facing is that I need an ExplicitWaity before clicking on the button `btnSearch`as it throws a a NoSuchElementFoundException. Since I use the [FindsBy] attribute, I figure there should be some way to check how the webElement was found/created? How can I do this? Or how I can have neat code and use ExplicitWait on a Page Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for an element to be present/enabled/clickable, you can use a waiter with the `ElementToBeClickable` condition:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "searchButton")]
public IWebElement btnSearch { get; set; }

public void SelectOperator(String name, String establishmentNumber)
{
    this.txtName.SetInputField(name);
    this.txtEstablishmentNumber.SetInputField(establishmentNumber);                

    new WebDriverWait(SeleniumTests.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(this.btnSearch))
        .Click();
}
```

Comment: This works occassionally, but also sometimes throws an TargetInvocationException occurred in WebDriver.Support.dll. Do you know how to fix this? It is highly important for the success of our project. Thanks!

Comment: What is the inner exception? You should create a new question, it seems to be a different issue.